# Getting Area from GeoGraphics

Tags: graphics, image-processing, geography, geographics

I want to find the area covered by the reservoir of a dam using a satellite image.

This is what I have so far.

```
DamPosition = DamData[Entity["Dam", "TehriDam::q2zsw"], "Position"]
```

Which returns the coordinates. And then, I use some image manipulation to isolate the dam from `geoImage`.

```
geoImage = 
 DeleteSmallComponents[
  Dilation[
   Graphics[
    Select[Cases[
      GeoGraphics[
       GeoBoundingBox[GeoPosition[{30.377778`, 78.480556`}]], 
       GeoBackground -> 
        "VectorMinimal"], {Directive[{___, 
         RGBColor[0.6, 0.807843137254902`, 1.], ___}], ___}, 
      Infinity], Not@*FreeQ[Polygon]]], 0]]
```

[image: This is the image that I get after image manipulation]

Now, all I want to do is find the area of the blue - shaded region.

I know I can do this manually using the getcoordinates tool, but that seems too unreliable and tedious to do. I'm looking for an automated way to do it.

PS : Using GetCoordinates, we can use the following code

```
    damContour = {{36.14216500804076`, -98.66601000992658`},
   {36.15131161335255`, -98.6549477815357`},
   {36.1501032100147`, -98.62214348441108`},
   {36.15000037203102`, -98.60908533742007`},
   {36.13193732747872`, -98.58352140011719`},
   {36.10128112030604`, -98.57004960135653`},
   {36.08009879008038`, -98.6043835918035`},
   {36.1172565230945`, -98.61315564049649`},
   {36.12831708030723`, -98.62663775701455`},
   {36.13202116684048`, -98.64507269213401`},
   {36.13870030579935`, -98.6454368865287`},
   {36.13708633726377`, -98.6568745786338`}};
GeoGraphics[{White, Thick, Line[GeoPosition[damContour]]}, 
 GeoRange -> {{36.05, 36.17}, {-98.7, -98.52}}, 
 GeoRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], GeoBackground -> "Satellite"];
GeoArea[Polygon[GeoPosition[damContour]]]
```

Comment: "Area of a dam"?  Not of a *lake*??

Comment: Oops - I meant the area covered by the reservoir of the dam

Comment: Might be worth working with an [equal-area projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-area_projection). The available projections in WL can be found via `GeoProjectionData["EqualArea"]`.

Comment: @GregHurst could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see you were using `GeoArea`. If you weren't, then the area would depend on the projection.

Answer (score 3):

First I get just the image of the area with a 10 km scale bar:

```
DamPosition = DamData[Entity["Dam", "TehriDam::q2zsw"], "Position"];

l = 10;
geoImage = 
 GeoGraphics[GeoBoundingBox[DamPosition], 
  GeoBackground -> "StreetMapNoLabels", 
  GeoScaleBar -> Placed[Quantity[{0, l}, "Kilometers"], {Right, Top}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I find the areas that have the color of water, and `Binarize`:

```
waterColor = RGBColor[0.6, 0.807843137254902, 1.];
lake = ColorDetect[geoImage, ColorsNear[waterColor, 0]] // Binarize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I get just the part that looks like the reservoir by taking the largest component of `lake`:

```
res = SelectComponents[lake, "Count", -1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I get the scale bar by finding the black parts of `geoImage`:

```
bar = Binarize@ColorDetect[geoImage, RGBColor[0, 0, 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the scale bar without the labels, I select the longest length component of `bar`:

```
bar = SelectComponents[bar, "Length", -1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I get the pixel length of the scale bar by grabbing the largest side length of its `BoundingBox`, and calculate the scale by dividing `l` by the pixel length of the scale bar

```
v = First@Values@ComponentMeasurements[bar, "BoundingBox"];
len = Max[Abs[First[v] - Last[v]]];
scale = Quantity[l, "km"]/len
(*Quantity[0.04329, "Kilometers"] *)
```

The area of each pixel is just `scale^2`:

```
pixelArea=scale^2;
```

The total area of `res` is now just the total of the image (since it's binarized) times `pixelArea

```
Total@Flatten[ImageData[res]]*pixelArea

(*Quantity[20.5019, ("Kilometers")^2]*)
```

So the area of the reservoir is $\approx 20.5 \mathrm{km}^2$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Just a small question - shouldn't the scale be 5KM instead of 0.5KM? The answer is skewed by a factor of 10. Also, is there a way to find the scale/unitpixel programmatically?

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need to get my vision checked. Added an automated way to get scale.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer that I have received

```
DamPosition = DamData[Entity["Dam", "TehriDam::q2zsw"], "Position"];

l = 10;
geoImage = 
 GeoGraphics[GeoBoundingBox[DamPosition], 
  GeoBackground -> "StreetMapNoLabels", 
  GeoScaleBar -> Placed[Quantity[{0, l}, "Kilometers"], {Right, Top}]]
waterColor = RGBColor[0.6, 0.807843137254902, 1.];
geoImage = ColorDetect[geoImage, ColorsNear[waterColor, 0]] // 
Binarize
 ImageResize[geoImage, {128,128}]
 Area[ImageMesh[geoImage]]
```

This becomes useful when we resize all images to a standard size and then compare the area of different dams.